# Slack api error nongranular_bot_token_not_allowed

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've got a slack bot, which is a member of a private channel in slack. I want to use this bot to invite other users to the channel. As far as I understand, having a bot token and bot scope is enough to be able to do this (https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.invite). However, I receive a response:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "nongranular_bot_token_not_allowed"
}
```

I wasn't able to find this error in slack docs or anywhere. What does it mean?

Comment: Interesting error. how did you create the token exactly? by creating and installing your own Slack app or by installing the bot user app? Something else?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually, and I don't quite understand the difference. The bot was created by our slack admins by request from our team. Initially it only sent messages with buttons, but now we also need it to invite people to private channels (the channels are created by another app, which has a user token, and it invites our bot)

Comment: there are two ways to create bot tokens AFAIK. By creating and installing a new Slack app that has a bot user, or by installing the "Bots" app from Slack.

Comment: I tested it and I get the same error if I use a bot token created a normal Slack app. Which is strange since the documentation clearly states that a bot token would work.

Comment: I see. Ours is a new Slack app with a bot user

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Either the documentation is wrong or their is problem with the API method. So I would suggest to open a support request to Slack to clarify.

Comment: In the meantime you can as a workaround of course use the access token of your app. That would surely work after you added the `groups:write` write permissions and reinstalled it to your workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Slack support team replied that this is a new, yet undocumented error. Also, the docs are incorrect and bots aren't actually allowed to invite users to private channels:

> That's actually a new error that is going to be documented.
>
> Meanwhile, it seems that we, unfortunately, don't give app bot tokens permission to invite users to channels. There is an issue in the docs with how this is documented though.

Comment: Please don’t forget to mark your answer as solution. Thanks